# React Native - JS Promise does not resolve when calling from a native module

Tags: android, react-native

I have an Android native module in a React Native app. From there I start an Activity and on some event from it (if it matters, this event is not received from the Main thread), I'm sending an event to JS via:

```
reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName, params);
```

When I'm catching the event in JS I do:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Resolving promise")
        resolve('value')
      }, 1000)
```

The problem is that the promise does not resolve after 1 second, but only when I quit the Activity (the one that I called from a native module). To be precise the function in `setTimeout` is not called after 1 sec

I'm pretty new to React native so I'm not sure what blocks the promise resolution. Any hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe another your code blocked event loop in JS thread until you remove your activity from back stack?